# Modernizr load how to

Tags: modernizr

My reference to google hosted jQuery seems to want to load as an image somehow:

[image]

Also, how is modernizr loading ga.js, plugins.js and main.js? And how do I prevent it from loading the local version of jQuery?

These are my two script tags:

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Modernizr.load(['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', 'js/less.js']);</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

See if you have any luck with the following to load the jquery and less scripts:

```
<script>
Modernizr.load({
load: [ 
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", 
"js/less.js"
]
});
</script>
```

**Update**

> Also, how is modernizr loading ga.js, plugins.js and main.js? And how do I prevent it from loading the local version of jQuery?

If I'm reading your question correctly, at the moment modernizr isn't loading ga.js, plugins.js or main.js. You would either need to add them to the above load script or reference them with another script tag. Likewise for your local version of jQuery.

Good luck!